# Riccati equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The derivations of the Riccati equation from a linear equation, and the limit for which the algebraic Riccati equation is valid, are pretty straightforward to me. What is not clear to me is, if the resulting equation is going to be integrated numerically anyway, what is the advantage of integrating the Riccati equation rather than the original linear equation?